# Auto Connecting with jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

Hello StackOverflow community, this is my first post, so please be gentle, since I don't know the etiquette here yet.
Anyways, can someone help me auto connect with `jsPlumb`? I just can't figure out how to do it, using the styles in addEndpoint function. Hope there are some clever people, that are willing to help me & figure it out. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schlumpfpirat/so03ck9s/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add uuids for each endpoints. Using your current setup:

```
function addEndpoints(id,target,source) {

    // Setting Source-/Startpoint Style
    var sourceEndpoint = {
        endpoint:"Dot",
        isSource:true,
        ...
        uuid: "xxx0"
    },      

    // Setting Targetpoint Style
    targetEndpoint = {
        endpoint: ["Rectangle", {width:13, height:13}], 
        isTarget:true,      
        ...
        uuid: "xxx1"
    };  

    ...

}
```

and connect them in your init functions:

```
jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:["xxx0","xxx1"] });
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! Any way of doing this without assigning an UUID? Since it would always have to be unique, I'd have to write some more code to create unique UUIDs.. can't I just somehow add the endpoints and then find out which UUID the "TopCenter" anchor of a container has?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to connect existing endpoints without uuids. Besides, creating uuids can be as simple as creating ids within your addMain function.